# How to play sound in notification extension service?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My code:

```objc
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"autumn_leaves" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                               error:&error];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

[player play];
```

How can I play a sound using avplayer in notification extension service?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Does your code not work as expected? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes i have write the code for play sound but nothing happened. No error and no sound

Comment: Have you checked soundFileURL is not nil? What value does it give [player  duration]? what is current device [player currentDevice]? Are your speakers muted?

Comment: Actually i want to play sound when device is in silent mode